# Titanium/Appcelerator - using picker for time, produces date object with local time difference

Tags: javascript, date, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using a picker (`Ti.UI.Picker`) and setting the type to `Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_TIME`. The purpose is to allow the user to change the time of a date entry in the database. The date is stored in a UTC timestamp. The flow goes like this:

1. User opens controller
2. The date is extracted from the DB, and stored as a Moment JS date object, using the `moment.utc()` method.
3. The user selects to open the picker to change the time
4. The `moment.toDate()` method is used to pass the required date object to the picker
5. The picker opens with time that has been corrected according to the timezone setting on their phone e.g: +1 hour.
6. When the user is done, the picker returns a date object, and the resulting time is not what they selected; in this case it's -1 hour.

I thought that by using `moment.utc()` I would be able to avoid this. But perhaps the picker does some internal stuff with a normal JavaScript date object, thus getting this adjustment in time.

Is there a way around this? My objective is that; if the original time is 13:00, I want the picker to open with 13:00, then if the user changes it to 15:00, I want the result from the picker to be 15:00 and the corresponding label to show as 15:00.

**Here is some sample code**

```
var moment = require('alloy/moment');

var time_unix = 1396815002000;
var date_obj = moment.utc(time_unix);

function updateTimeLabel() {
    $.timeLabel.setText(date_obj.format('HH:mm'));
}

function onTimeClick() {
    var pickerView = Titanium.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor: "#FFF",
        height: 280,
        bottom :-280,
        zIndex: 1000
    }); 
    var cancel = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title:'Cancel',
        style: Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.BORDERED
    }); 
    var done = Ti.UI.createButton({ 
        title:'Done',   
        style: Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.DONE
    });     
    var spacer = Ti.UI.createButton({
        systemButton: Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.FLEXIBLE_SPACE
    });
    var toolbar = Ti.UI.iOS.createToolbar({
        top: 0,
        barColor: '#000',
        items:[cancel,spacer,done]
    });
    var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
        type: Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_TIME,
        value: date_obj.toDate(), // does the problem occur here?
        minDate: new Date('1950-01-01'),
        maxDate: new Date('2050-01-01'),
        top: 45
    });
    cancel.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log('cancel pressed');
        pickerView.animate({bottom: 0, duration: 500});
    });
    done.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        date_obj = moment.utc(picker.getValue());
        updateTimeLabel(); // result is 1 hour less than picker
        pickerView.animate({bottom: -280, duration: 500});
    });
    pickerView.add(toolbar);
    pickerView.add(picker);
    $.win.add(pickerView);
    // picker opens with time that is +1 hour
    pickerView.animate({bottom: 0, duration: 500});
}


$.win.open();
updateTimeLabel();
```

**Screenshot**
[image: Screen shot of Ti.UI.Picker showing incorrect time]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I'm setting the default value with the moment format method, and simple dates and times:

```
picker.setValue(moment(someTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

and for time pickers:

```
picker.setValue(moment(someTime).format("HH:mm"));
```

It works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue but realized the -1hr difference was due to daylight saving time, appending toLocaleString() to the returned value fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You use the (unix) timestamp to store the date/time. However when displaying it, you use momentJS Timezone : 
http://momentjs.com/timezone/

On another note, you "may" want to listen to the change event to update the label.

Answer (score -1):

Just a quick "guess". Are you by any chance in a place that has daylight savings right now?

As I understand it "UTC" (not specific to Moment) is the "real" GMT time without daylight savings. So that *could* be what is teasing you.

If so, could you then "convert" the UTC time to show the "same" hours in the users "local" time (or at least with the daylight savings correction)? And then convert back once the user closes the dialog.

*Someone may be able to give you a better explanation - and solution ;-)*

/John

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I'm hoping to avoid any timezone/daylight correction, as I have heard that is fraught with pitfalls - but I definitely would welcome an answer that solves the problem reliably for any user in any timezone.